# How do I install ansible version 2.7 via brew in order to use kubespray on macos?

Tags: macos, ansible, homebrew

I'm trying to run kubespray on macos. However, brew only has ansible at version 2.8 and kubespray requires 2.7. How can I install ansible 2.7 via brew?

Answer (score 4):

Brew doesn't have a formula for ansible prior to 2.8; however, you can install the previous 2.7.10 method by using the git commit from brew on github to reference that version and switch.

```
brew install ansible 
brew unlink ansible
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/0b01263b6e11cb11d583e1e6cf870386f092cf43/Formula/ansible.rb
brew switch ansible 2.7.10
ansible --version
```